# Can't get solidity to install on mac

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to get solidity installed so that I can write contracts in Atom. I got this Atom package: https://atom.io/packages/atom-ethereum-interface

In it, it says to run `geth --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "localhost" console` and then `eth.getCompilers()` to make sure solidity is installed. I don't get any results, so I went to try to install solidity.

I found this article: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html followed all of the steps in it, then ran the two commands to start geth and check for compilers, still nothing.

So I found this article: http://dipl.me:3000/greeter which says to run:

```
brew update
brew install cpp-ethereum
brew linkapps cpp-ethereum
which solc

Take note of the path given by the last line, you'll need it soon.
```

Again, I get no errors, but do not get any results in the prompt when I type `which solc`.

So I ran the geth command again and checked for compilers, still nothing. What am I doing wrong and how can I get this thing running on my mac?

Comment: im having the same problem

Comment: ditto- what's up with this :/